# Django 2.2 Кастомная модель пользователя (постоянно не совпадают пароли)

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-admin

После создания кастомной модели пользователя и регистрации нового пользователя в **админке!!!** не получается залогиниться с сайта, ошибка - *Please enter a correct Почта and password. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive.*

Python 3.7, Django 2.2, на сайте не допускается регистрация пользователей, только из админки и только админом.

**MOELS.PY**

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
def create_user(self, email, first_name=None, password=None, is_active=True, 
is_staff=False, is_admin=False):
    if not email:
        raise ValueError('Поле email должно быть заполнено')
    if not password:
        raise ValueError('Неверный пароль')

    user = self.model(
        email=self.normalize_email(email),
        first_name=first_name
    )

    user.set_password(password)
    user.staff = is_staff
    user.admin = is_admin
    user.active = is_active
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user

def create_staffuser(self, email, first_name=None, password=None):
    user = self.create_user(
        email,
        first_name=first_name,
        password=password,
        is_staff=True
    )
    return user

def create_superuser(self, email, first_name=None, password=None):
    user = self.create_user(
        email,
        first_name=first_name,
        password=password,
        is_staff=True,
        is_admin=True
    )
    return user


class RealUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    first_name = models.CharField('Имя', max_length=120)
    last_name = models.CharField('Фамилия', max_length=120, db_index=True)
    patronymic = models.CharField('Отчество', max_length=120)
    phone_number = models.CharField('Телефон', max_length=15, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField('Почта', max_length=30, unique=True)
    image = models.ImageField('Фото', default='user.png', upload_to='user_img')
    description = models.TextField('О себе', default='')
    department = models.ForeignKey(UserDepartment, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, verbose_name='Отдел')
    position = models.ForeignKey(UserPosition, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, verbose_name='Должность')
    status = models.ForeignKey(UserStatus, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, verbose_name='Статус')
    active = models.BooleanField('Работает', default=True)
    staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name']

    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return f'СОТРУДНИК: {self.first_name} {self.last_name}, ПОЧТА: {self.email}, ТЕЛЕФОН: {self.phone_number}'
        # return self.email

    def get_full_name(self):
        return f'{self.first_name} {self.last_name}, ПОЧТА: {self.email}'
        # return self.email

    def get_short_name(self):
        return f'{self.last_name}, ПОЧТА: {self.email}'
        # return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.staff

    @property
    def is_admin(self):
        return self.admin

    @property
    def is_active(self):
        return self.active

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('employee_detail', args=[str(self.email)])

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Сотрудник'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Сотрудники'
```

---

**ADMIN.PY**

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import ReadOnlyPasswordHashField
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from django.contrib import admin
from django import forms
from .models import *

User = get_user_model()


class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Пароль', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Подтверждение паорля', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = RealUser
        fields = ('email', 'first_name',)

    def clean_password2(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('password1')
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('password2')

        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Пароли не совпадают')

        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data['password1'])

        if commit:
            user.save()

        return user


class UserChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = ReadOnlyPasswordHashField()

    class Meta:
        model = RealUser
        fields = (
            'email',
            'password',
            'first_name',
            'trainee',
            'manager',
            'head',
            'staff',
            'admin',
        )

        def clean_password(self):
            return self.initial['password']


class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = [
        'email',
        'last_name',
    ]

    list_filter = [
        'active',
        'head',
        'manager',
        'trainee',
        'staff',
    ]

    list_display = [
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'email',
        'phone_number',
        'active',
        'head',
        'manager',
        'trainee',
        'staff',
        'admin',
    ]

    class Meta:
        model = User


admin.site.register(UserDepartment)
admin.site.register(UserPosition)
admin.site.register(UserStatus)
admin.site.register(RealUser, UserAdmin)
admin.site.register(GuestUser)
admin.site.register(GuestUserStatus)

admin.site.unregister(Group)
```

---

**LOGIN.HTML**

```
{% extends 'core/index.html' %}

{% block title %}
    Вход в личный кабинет
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>{{ user.first_name }}</h1>
    <div class="content-section">
        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">
                    Log in
                </legend>
                {{ form.as_p }}
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">
                    Login
                </button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

---

**SETTINGS.PY**

```
***
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.RealUser'
***
```

---

Я заметил вот такой момент (что-то мне подсказывает что проблема именно в этом). Если зайти в админку в профиль админа, то пароль будет представлен хэшированным, а у пользователя в виде текста:
[image: Скрин админа]

[image: Скрин пользователя]

---

ADMIN.PY (исправленный)

```
class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Пароль', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Подтверждение паорля', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = RealUser
        fields = ('email', 'first_name',)

    def clean_password2(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('password1')
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('password2')

        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Пароли не совпадают')

        return password2

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data['password1'])
        user.save()

        return user
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас проблема в том, что вы сохраняете пользователя только при commit==True

```
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data['password1']) 

        if commit: # Не работает из-за этого. Уберите и будет счастье. Почему - см. ниже
            user.save()
```

Обновите на

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data['password1'])
        user.save()
```

ModelAdmin

```
# django.contrib.admin.options.ModelAdmin
# 969 строка

    def save_form(self, request, form, change):
        """
        Given a ModelForm return an unsaved instance. ``change`` is True if
        the object is being changed, and False if it's being added.
        """
        return form.save(commit=False)
```

Comment: Нет, все равно не работает ( Я внес изменения, потом полностью удалил все миграции и БД, заново создал все и все равно не работает... пользователя вписываю в поля через копипаст, так что опечатка исключена...)

Comment: обновил ответ. попробуйте. и добавьте в вопрос, что стало после обновления, чтобы проверить

Comment: Все так же... Ответ обновил.

Comment: кстати, с сайта получается войти как админ, но как пользователь не получается

Comment: Войти пытаетесь через ту же форму, что для адмики? Если да, добавьте одному из пользователей права сотрудника (is_staff=True) и ипроверьте его. насколько помню, django не пускает обычных польхзователей без прав, не сообщая реальной причины

Comment: нет, пытаюсь через форму на сайте, форму входа как в админке не использую (для пользователей). Попробовал добавить is_staff, не работает

Comment: Это для вновь созданного пользователя? так уточнение

Comment: Пароли до сих пор не хешируются?

Comment: Да, только для вновь созданных. Нет пароль не хешируются...

Comment: Добавтьте, пожалуйста, блок в котором использутся UserCreationForm

Comment: Так я добавил, в вопросе в самом низу ADMIN.PY (исправленный)

Comment: не, я имел в виду куда вы ее вставляете. нигде не видно form = ... в UserAdmin

Comment: Точно!!! Спасибо большое, оказывается описывать форму для входа в admin.py вместо forms.py это плохая идея.... В общем все перенес в формс и все заработало...